# How to add 'new' text in navigation drawer item?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationitem

I've a navigation drawer and I want to add just a 'new' text besides the item in navigation drawer like this gmail app navigation drawer.

I just want to add text i don't want to make it functional or more complicated.
please suggest me how I can achieve this goal.

Thanks In Advance!!

[image]

Here is my DrawerLayout in `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_color"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and `activity_main_drawer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:title="Home"/>

    <item android:title="EXPLORE">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_FeaturedListing"
                android:icon="@drawable/feature_icon"
                android:title="Featured Listings" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_food"
                android:icon="@drawable/food"
                android:title="Restaurants/Dining" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_bars"
                android:icon="@drawable/bars"
                android:title="Bars/Nightlife"
                />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_hotelnlodging"
                android:icon="@drawable/hotel"
                android:title="Hotels/Lodging" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_taxi"
                android:icon="@drawable/taxi_icon"
                android:title="Taxis/Tour Guide" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_tours"
                android:icon="@drawable/tour"
                android:title="Tour Operators" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_fun"
                android:icon="@drawable/fun"
                android:title="Entertainment" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <group>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_favorites"
            android:icon="@drawable/favorite"
            android:title="Bookmarks" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_deals"
            android:icon="@drawable/deal"
            android:title="Deals &amp; Promotions" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_blog"
            android:icon="@drawable/blog"
            android:title="Blog" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_vlogs"
            android:icon="@drawable/vlog"
            android:title="Vlogs/Videos"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_points"
            android:icon="@drawable/points"
            android:title="Dashboard" />
    </group>




    <item android:title="Login &amp; Contact">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
                    android:icon="@drawable/profile"
                    android:title="My Profile" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_social"
                    android:icon="@drawable/social_icon"
                    android:title="Connect With Us"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_feedback"
                    android:icon="@drawable/feedback"
                    android:title="Feedback"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_contact"
                    android:icon="@drawable/contact"
                    android:title="Contact" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_help"
                    android:icon="@drawable/question"
                    android:title="Help"
                    ></item>
            </menu>
        </item>

</menu>
```

I want to add 'new' text inside an item.

Comment: please paste your code here.

Comment: You can replace the NavigationView with a fragment and use recyclerview to show the drawer items. You can design the items in whatever way you want.

Comment: Thanks Guruji and @WOLF.L I've added the code, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can create custom row, inside DrawerLayout take LinearLayout inside that take TextView on right side and set background color and text color to TextView.

Create global instance of this TextView i would suggest to create BaseClass of your activity and there you update this count of TextView.

If you want some more information then please post your code snippet so as to guide you through the same.

Comment: I've added the code.can you please give me some code regarding this.Thanks so much for your comment